# XSLT for dynamic tag passed from Java Program

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xalan, jaxp

My requirement is to do a XML A to XML B transformation. The Tag in which I read from XML A should be configurable, it is a kind of iteartion of lists. If there is any new tag present in XML A, it should be dealt by adding entries in configuration file for Java and programatically which in turn should be reflected in XSLT and transformed to XML B.

I'm using Java. Is it possible by passing parameters? as my requirement need the parameters are passed in a loop or a List.

I'm new to XSLT and any info link on this would be very much appreciated.

Source XML - There can be more like yearly, weekly etc here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Report>
    <Daily>
        <input>1234</input>
    </Daily>
    <Monthly>
        <input>8678</input>
    </Monthly>  
</Report>
```

Target XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Report>
    <Value>
        <Attribute>
            <name>Daily</name>
            <values>1234</values>
        </Attribute>
        <Attribute>
            <name>Monthly</name>
            <values>8678</values>
        </Attribute>
    </Value>
</Report>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example or A which you want to get to B and example of B ..

Comment: Disagree. This question is not asking for any external resource, it defines a clear target, and asking for help how to get to the solution. Obviously OP had no information about some features like `name()` function, otherwise it complies all SO standards.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `name()` or the `local-name()` function for the currently selected node.

See how to [selecting current element name in XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154533/selecting-current-element-name-in-xslt)

Here's the sketch of the code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/Report/">
        <Value>
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <Attribute>
                <name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
                </name>
                <values>
                    <xsl:value-of select="./input"/>
                </values>
            </Attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </Value>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? It's not about finding the name of the context item.

Comment: @MathiasMüller OP wants to transform `<Daily>` into `<name>Daily</name>`. He needs to detect the current node name, and use it in an `<xsl:element>` tag.

Comment: Retracted my downvote. Since you edited your answer, it makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @GaborSch Thanks for your solution. But this is not working as expected.  can u please explain on this

Comment: You need to create a `<root>` tag around your xml tags. Then it will work. As you know, in XML you can have only one root node, all other must be child nodes to that node.

Comment: I updated the code to fully match your source and target XML.